# TF Learn & TF: Which output node to use when freezing a graph? - Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tflearn

I currently have a binary image classifier. This is for my undergraduate dissertation, so any help would be very much appreciated.

The model performs well when I am loading and using the model as the '.model' file within the kernel. What I want, is to freeze the graph and deploy the classifier to a portable solution, e.g a local Flask web server.

Whilst following tutorials regarding the freezing of the graph, it is apparent that I must define output nodes. I am struggling to select which nodes I should be parsing at this stage. I have printed out the list of available nodes using

```
[print(n.name) for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
```

This presents me with a huge list of options. Using my 'targets/Y' as an output node, the graph does not freeze any variables and 'frozen_model.pb' has a size of 1kb. When I select the 'FullyConnected_1/Softmax' as the output nodes, a number of around 60/70 variables get saved and the file size is larger, around what I would expect (30mb or so). When I use this frozen graph to classify a test image, I get basically a 50/50 split on the confidence of my two available classes (a clueless classifier): [[0.49903905 0.5009609 ]] - to be exact.

What I extrapolate from this, in relation to the result and where in the list of available nodes the 'FullyConnected_1/Softmax' is placed, this is freezing the model at the stage prior to any training or optimising at all.

I am sure you will want more information, but I don't want to post absolutely everything and confuse the post. Please could somebody help me with this, I will provide more code and information as you need.

Thank you very much!